# Should Jewish Christians not work on Saturday or Sunday?

Tags: christian-living, judaism, sabbath, jews

I am Jewish, and this presents additional issues for me if I am considering Christianity, that non Jewish Christians don't have. For example, as far as I understand the Catholic Church has held that the covenant with the Jews has never been revoked

http://www.jcrelations.net/The_covenant_has_never_been_revoked.2250.0.html
http://www.haaretz.com/jewish-world/jewish-world-news/1.560784

I mean if you read your own Bible, you can see a very strong case for believing that the Covenant Israel had with God was binding for ever and on all of their descendants - which includes Jews today:

http://biblelaw101.com/Home/Questions%20on%20the%20Law%20of%20God.htm

So Jews are instructed to rest on the "Sabbath day". And it is indisputable that throughout the entire time of Jewish History, that was the 7th day. Genesis talks about God resting on the 7th day. Yet, the Ecumenical councilat Nicaea ultimately proclaimed that Christians' sabbath should be on the 1st day of the week - which we call Sunday in English.

So what's a Jew supposed to do? When they are a Christian, that is! In your answer, please tell us what your denomination is and what position it holds on the matter.

PS: If your answer includes saying that the Covenant with Israel has been superceded, then please explain how exactly we are supposed to read the verses in biblelaw101.com above

Comment: Are you asking for the Catholic answer? What sort of Christian? The answer may differ in that group's opinion.

Comment: @mxyzplk I haven't made up my mind what branch of Christianity is more likely to have things right, so anyone who answers should answer from their OWN denomination of course. I might as well as Catholics, yes. But I am also interested in what Protestants have to say. Should I file two different questions, differing only in who is being addressed -- Catholics or Protestants? There are so many denominations of Protestants.

Comment: This question asks for pastoral advice as I will show, so it should be placed on hold. Rabbi Akiba said that it is better to work on the Sabbath than to rely on charity. Early Christians worked on the Sabbath and Sunday (7 days a week) because they had to or be fired or if they were slaves, slightly worse. It never had anything to do with the 'first day'. It was about money for the bosses. And so it is now for everyone. Do you have to work? If you do, only keep Friday night. Let your wife light a candle. Drink a glass of wine and thank God for the creation and your life. If you ask ...

Comment: @TheFreemason This is not a duplicate of that question because it has a different focus. As a Jewish Christian specifically, should the Jew feel free to start working on the Sabbath day? Gentile Christians were never under the Covenant with Israel so they did not have to stop working on Saturday. But the Covenant with Israel is for all generations, so Jews have to face this question. It is entirely different from "why do Christians celebrate on Sunday"?

Comment: @gideonmarx In the early 20th century, Jews in the Conservative movement (not orthodox) in the USA would apologize to God that they would had to go and work on Saturday. Today, there are religious protections and I do not feel I "have" to work on Saturday at all. That is not the issue here. The question is, once a Jew becomes a Christian, are they entirely free from the Law and now able to work on Saturday? This question is specifically about that aspect, since it comes up every 7 days. Christians who trumpet "we are not under the Law" and how Jews should understand this trumpet.

Comment: All Christians that believe that Jesus was the Messiah should follow His example and keep Shabat. He explained perfectly what the laws of Shabat are. So incredibly perfectly ... It is all so simple.

Comment: @gideonmarx so you obviously don't think that Jewish Christians should work on the Sabbath. But many Christians think it's ok to not observe Saturday since we are no longer under the law. My question is to them :)

Comment: @gregorymagarshak if you read the answers there, IMHO, you will find your answer.  The questions may be scoped differently, but the answers apply.

Answer (score 2):

In the book of Romans Paul clearly shows that this is a matter for each individual to make up their own mind about. All Christians have freedom from the Mosaic Law, so decide for yourself what you think will help you to practice godliness and be in the best position to serve others. And keep reconsidering it, because it may be wise to change your decision later.

> One person considers one day more sacred than another; another considers every day alike. Each of them should be fully convinced in their own mind. Whoever regards one day as special does so to the Lord. Whoever eats meat does so to the Lord, for they give thanks to God; and whoever abstains does so to the Lord and gives thanks to God. For none of us lives for ourselves alone, and none of us dies for ourselves alone. If we live, we live for the Lord; and if we die, we die for the Lord. So, whether we live or die, we belong to the Lord. For this very reason, Christ died and returned to life so that he might be the Lord of both the dead and the living. (Romans 14:5-9, NIV)

Comment: This is getting more and more off topic. Please make other questions to discuss these things.

Answer (score -1):

This should be considered a Catholic Response.

**Should Jewish Christians not work on Saturday or Sunday?** I feel that if you can manage your life to allow time for the day of rest then you have been given an advantage. For projects and work take away from family time and rest. That being said there are exceptions, and there are also ones feeling of guilt.

So let us look to why there was a commandment for the Sabbath. The Jews were being treated as slaves, and (I take a logical guess here) where probably forced to work every day.

**Exodus 20:2**

> I am the Lord your God, who brought you out of the land of Egypt, out of the house of bondage.

So let us look at this reasonably. If God decided to do the "work" involved in freeing the slaves, what benefit do they receive if they are continued to work as they where forced to do previously?

So that was purpose, let us see from the viewpoint of function. In function the rest is to give peace, rest, and the rebuilding of the bodies. So a problem started to rise within the observance of the day. Not about the observance of the day, but how the day was observed.

**Psalm 95:7-11 NKJV**

> For He is our God, And we are the people of His pasture, And the sheep of His hand. Today, if you will hear His voice: 8 “Do not harden your hearts, as in the rebellion, As in the day of trial in the wilderness, 9 When your fathers tested Me; They tried Me, though they saw My work. 10 For forty years I was grieved with that generation, And said, ‘It is a people who go astray in their hearts, And they do not know My ways.’ 11 So I swore in My wrath, ‘They shall not enter My rest.’”

So we can clearly see that how the heart would receive his word, is an important part of observing this commandment. Now logically what is more important? To observe the day with the right heart? Or, to observe the day with the wrong heart? Now if to observe the day with the hardened heart God swore the he would not let the entrance into rest. I choose that observing the day with the good heart is the right choice.

Defining work is important: for what is done out of love, may not be considered work. Things done for money usually are considered work. Yet if that money is for the family, and not for selfish gain, that may also not be considered work. Yet this is from a perspective of conscience. For a radiant attitude can be drawn to scorn when guilt weighs on the mind.

Notice that the rest was taken away with the word "Today".

**Psalm 95:7b NKJV**

> ...Today, if you will hear His voice

Therefore, we can reason that if the Good Heart is today, then rest can occur today as well!

**Hebrews 4:8-11**

> For if Joshua had given them rest, then He would not afterward have spoken of another day. 9 There remains therefore a rest for the people of God. 10 For he who has entered His rest has himself also ceased from his works as God did from His. 11 Let us therefore be diligent to enter that rest, lest anyone fall according to the same example of disobedience.

Now if one enters into the rest "Today" and "Today" occurs "Everyday". Then "Today" also occurs on the "Sabbath". Yet I do also try to treat the Shabbat special, as a time for family and rest.

During the Ecumenical councilat Nicaea Constantine was in a position to create peace and he took it. The original reason for the 1st day of the week - which we call Sunday in English was this:

Some observed shabbat, and did not want to do work on the Saturday. So they where asked to gather on the first day of the week for money collections.

**1 Corinthians 16:2 NKJV**

> On the first day of the week let each one of you lay something aside, storing up as he may prosper, that there be no collections when I come.

When they where gathered, some would eat and get drunk, while others where put to shame.

**1 Corinthians 11:22 NKJV**

> What! Do you not have houses to eat and drink in? Or do you despise the church of God and shame those who have nothing? What shall I say to you? Shall I praise you in this? I do not praise you.

Therefore there was a call to order.

**1 Corinthians 14:33 NKJV**

> For God is not the author of confusion but of peace, as in all the churches of the saints.

And a request that all join in the Lord's Supper.

**1 Corinthians 11:20 NKJV**

> Therefore when you come together in one place, it is not to eat the Lord’s Supper.

Since the church members were to be poor. They could fulfill the sacraments.

**Leviticus 5:13 NKJV**

> ...The rest shall be the priest’s as a grain offering.

For burnt offerings part of were no longer needed for Leviticus 5:11-13.

**Isaiah 1:11 NKJV**

> To what purpose is the multitude of your sacrifices to Me?” Says the Lord. “I have had enough of burnt offerings of rams And the fat of fed cattle. I do not delight in the blood of bulls, Or of lambs or goats.

Personally I suggest you take the day. Yet if "Father God" is in need of your body. How can he hold it against you if you do his will? For God is not hypocritical. Yet all things are simplified to love the one next to you as yourself. Also I find that family house work on Sunday provides its own rest in the afternoon. As I have the time to write this for you because of this.

I choose to rest on Saturday, then take service on Sunday at 8 AM at the Catholic Church for the sacrifice, then 10:30 AM at the Assemblies of God for fellowship and praise. Yet each has their own way, and I don't always get to play out my routine. Family trips sometimes gets me driving on Saturday, and I do admit I sometimes load the car, when I could prepare that on Fridays, or unload when we arrive. I feel however that deeds done for family environmental settings for the comfort of my family, or to reduce family anxiety possibilities, all fall within Loving the ones next to me. God has not killed me yet, and if I do these things in error, then I will learn them from him. As of yet however, my heart does not condemn me, and though ignorance is not an excuse. In this I do not believe that I error, that does not mean that I do not. Yet the Lord is merciful, and I am grateful.